# Importing Multiple CSV Files into Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have multiple very similar CSV files saved in the same directory which I want to import into Access in one go. I want them to all go to one table.

I did some research, taught myself some VBA basics and ended up with this script:

```
Public Function Import()
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean


blnHasFieldNames = True

strPath = "C:\Downloads\models"

strTable = "ModelData"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames


      strFile = Dir()
Loop

End Function
```

Trying to run the macro doesn't do anything and I'm stuck where to move forward from here.

I followed the same guide to running a macro in this quick minute long video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXdn7ca2BX4

I'm hoping I just missed a little step somewhere...

Also, I think I need to import each column in text format as one is not returning date/time data correctly.

I have tried to follow some similar questions on here however I do not really understand VBA coding :/

Any help would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For CSV file files you have to use DoCmd.TransferText:

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                   TableName:=strTable, _
                   FileName:=strPathFile, _
                   HasFieldNames:=True
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I've implemented your code into mine replacing "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames". Unfortunately the code still won't run! i'd love it even it showed an error message or something

Comment: `strPath` should have a path separator at the end `\\`. "C:\Downloads\models\"